# Updating a rss-feed continuously

Tags: php, time, rss, feed, bots

I'm creating a bot in PHP that continuously updates an RSS-feed and gathers information.
Every loop takes around 0.1 sec but sometimes it takes up to 9 sec to finish the cycle.

Why does this happen and is there a way around the problem? I need the bot to be as fast as possible as I'm trying to beat another bot that has the same purpose as mine.

Comment: Is the RSS feed on a server you control, or is it a third party site?

Comment: It is a third party site. The feed in question is this http://existenz.se/rss_feed.php

Comment: You have permission from the site's owner to poll the RSS feed so often, right? If someone would poll an RSS feed on my site without delay, they'd find their IP address blacklisted pretty quickly...

Comment: No, I don't have any specific permission to do this. It isn't really relevant at the moment as my bot isn't up 'n running while I'm not testing it's functions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're using the wrong tool for the job, if you need low latency push-updates you should go with XMPP, Comet or the like.

But if you have to go with RSS, is there any possibility that you keep the connection open instead of closing it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not run a background task on your machine? Using `crontab`on linux for example. That task parses your RSS feeds and writes the data to either a database or stores the parsed data into some kind of file format such as `XML` or `JSON`.